# MySQL (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Why am I getting `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`?

```
CREATE TABLE `company_pmc` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `pmcid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `company_properties` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `pmcid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_company_properties_company_pmc` FOREIGN KEY (`pmcid`) REFERENCES `company_pmc` (`pmcid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: You're creating the tables in the wrong order. When you're trying to create the foreign key constraint the table it refers to doesn't yet exist. You also need to ensure that the referenced column is indexed

Comment: Hi sorry I pasted them in reverse order but it does not matter, even if I start with company_pmc then company_properties I get the same error.

Comment: OK I found the issue, I had to add INDEX `pmcid` (`pmcid`) USING BTREE to company_pmc table.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue , https://dbfiddle.uk/wxFhho7n

Comment: So you created an index on `company_pmc.pmcid` but that column allows multiple rows to have the same value. So your other table can reference more than one row in `company_pmc`? What does that mean? Which one is the parent row?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]
Please read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Please avoid greetings, thanks, etc. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts.

Comment: This is a faq. Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se].